# How to add number as firebase realtime database child without converting to array?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a DB structure like the following:

[image: Example]

But it just converts the whole object to an array.

Here's what I get when I export this JSON.

```
[ null, {
  "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1" : {
    "added_at" : 1647966583316,
    "city" : "Test",
    "country" : "Test",
    "name" : "Test",
    "state" : "Test",
    "uid" : "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1"
  }
}, {
  "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1" : {
    "added_at" : 1647966583316,
    "city" : "Test",
    "country" : "Test",
    "name" : "Test",
    "state" : "Test",
    "uid" : "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1"
  }
} ]
```

I tried keeping the first child as 1 and the second as "first" (or some random string) and exported JSON and here's what I got...

```
{
  "1" : {
    "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1" : {
      "added_at" : 1647966583316,
      "city" : "Test",
      "country" : "Test",
      "name" : "Test",
      "state" : "Test",
      "uid" : "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1"
    }
  },
  "first" : {
    "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1" : {
      "added_at" : 1647966583316,
      "city" : "Test",
      "country" : "Test",
      "name" : "Test",
      "state" : "Test",
      "uid" : "oPNfOlBcS4gl3rvZ4CIme9MDk0p1"
    }
  }
}
```

I want something similar, but with children like "1", "2" instead.

Is it possible? Or using children like "first", "second" is the only solution right now?

Comment: What do you mean by "but with children like "1", "2" instead"? Show us a concrete example.

Comment: @AlexMamo the first screenshot is the example. I want it to be like a json object. But it's automatically converting to json array. (Like the first code snippet)

Comment: So to understand better, do you want to store multiple users into an array? Something like `stages/1/uid1`, `stages/1/uid2`, `stages/1/uid3`, and so on, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo each stage can contain multiple UIDs (https://imgur.com/a/NdXEV9m). Problem is that when I use child names like 1 or 2 it converts it to a json array (https://imgur.com/a/0MBm47b). But I want them to be structured like this https://imgur.com/a/rTBvO8K

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/NdXEV9m) isn't the same with [this](https://imgur.com/a/rTBvO8K)?

Comment: Nope it gives me an array. As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in the answer, Firebase automatically converts it to array when sequential numeric keys are used.

Comment: Seeing Franks'a answer, I understood it too. Good to hear you solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a node with sequential numeric keys (as in your screenshot and first JSON example), the Firebase SDK (and REST) API) automatically coerce that data to an array. There is no way to configure this behavior.

If you don't want the array coercion you should use non-numeric keys. My common approach is to prefix each key with a short string, like "key1", "key2", etc.

Also see: [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).